# Is there a way to sync the settings between local and remote for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So the latest version of vscode (1.46) provides preference sync, but I found I cannot enable this feature for remote vscode. Whenever I open remote folder, (e.g., in wsl), the option to sign in MS account and turn on preference sync is missing. Did I miss anything here or it is not supported?

figure below shows my local vscode instance with the preference sync:
[image: vscode local instance]

figure below shows my vscode instance for remote (wsl) without the preference sync option:
[image: vscode remote instance]

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

I was looking to enable this too, the first line is the answer I think. Only available for vscode insiders at the moment, maybe wait 'til next month

Comment: i am using insider version for both local and remote server ...